# symfony spraed pdf generator

Tags: symfony, pdf-generation

i have problem with lithuanian text in generated pdf.

I use spraed bundle for generate pdf

It example my code:

```
$html = $this->render('inc/print.html.twig', ['order' => $order, 'username' => $this->getUser()->getUsername()]);
    $pdfGenerator = $this->get('spraed.pdf.generator');

    return new Response($pdfGenerator->generatePDF($html),
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.date('Y-m-d').'out.pdf"'
        )
    );
```

PDFgenerate function after html document next parameter encoding, i try use win-1257 then i have eroglif in letter, if i use utf-8 lithuanian letter hide.

What i can to do?

Comment: have you tried ISO 8859-1?

Comment: no it not help me.